# Copy a specific text from lines using batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

My input file is like that:

```
text text
text text
text START_CHR line 1: text text text;
text START_CHR line 2: text text text;
text START_CHR line 3: text text text;
...
text text
eof
```

I need to copy all lines to a file between **START_CHR** and '**;**'.

Desired Output file:

```
START_CHR line 1: text text text;
START_CHR line 2: text text text;
START_CHR line 3: text text text;
```

or

```
   line 1: text text text
   line 2: text text text
   line 3: text text text
```

The **START_CHR** and ';' are delimiter of lines.

Unfortunately the findstr 'START_CHR' inFile.txt > outFile.txt result is:

```
text START_CHR line 1: text text text;
text START_CHR line 2: text text text;
text START_CHR line 3: text text text;
```

How I can get desired output file?

Cheers, Andy

Comment: Is the **START_CHR** _one character_ like `#`, or _a string_ like `START_CHR`?

Comment: Providing obfuscated examples usually leads to a script that does not work.

Comment: START_CHR is string. There are no spaces between characters in the lines.

Comment: @Andy, one option would be to use FINDSTR's /O option to your advantage as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=;" %%a in ('findstr "START_CHR" inFile.txt') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   echo !line:*START_CHR=!
)) > outFile.txt
```

Comment: It works!!! Cheers mate. It is possible to add characters at begin of line in same time?

Comment: Why it clears Output file after each run of FOR function?

Comment: @Andy, because a single redirection single means to overwrite the file.  If you need to append to the file then use two redirection symbols.

Comment: @Andy, put whatever you want to output before the line substitution: `echo Some other stuff !line:*START_CHR=!`